# C# client communicating with C++ server - server can read from socket but writing is unsuccessful

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a problem with my two programs - the C# client can successfully write data to the C++ client using a socket, but reading data from the server is unsuccessful.

Here's my C++ code:

```
int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

sockaddr_in sockad;
// sin_family, port etc defined here

bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&sockad, sizeof(sockad));

listen(sock, 15);

char buf;
stringstream ss;

while(running) {

    socklen_t sockl = sizeof(sockad);
    int sockd = accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&sockad, &sockl);

    while(recv(sockd, &buf, 1, 0) > 0) {
        ss << buf;
    }

    // THIS is printed
    cout << ss.str() << endl;

    string response = "asdgfh";

    // THIS never reaches the C# client
    write(sockd, response.c_str(), strlen(response.c_str()));

    close(sockd);
}

close(sock);
```

And here's my C# code:

```
string message = "message";
Int32 port = 4345;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("server.address.com", port);
NetworkStream stream = client.getStream();

Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

// THIS SUCCEEDS
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

// THIS FAILS, it also freezes the other program
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

So what's wrong with my code, or is this a server configuration issue or something like that?

Comment: I believe instead of "write" you may want to use "send" in the C++ layer.

Comment: @UrticaDioica here is an [article] outlining the send function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Changing the function to send didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @MattTanner: So we have to add the C tag for every question? Because Python is written in C, Java uses C libraries, The OS is written in C, ...? - Nonsense. Tags are related to the languages used. If you compile code with a C++ compiler, it has to be C++ compliant, not C compliant. Even for identical syntax, quite some semantics differ between these two languages. Not to mention features like `response.c_str()` (using `string` in general` in the code above.

Comment: A wild guess - if you add some time before calling `close(sockd);` for instance with a `cin.get()`, does the C# program accept it then?

Comment: Your C++ side really shouldn't have written anything - it should be blocked on the `recv` call forever, since the connection is never closed. So either there's something weird going on (another APC on the same thread?), or `recv` returned a SOCKET_ERROR at some point. Make sure to print out `WSAGetLastError()` if the return value of `recv` is smaller than zero and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a typical dead-lock.

On the C++ side, you keep reading from the socket until the TCP connection is (half-)closed. On the C# side, you write a bit of data and then wait *for the TCP connection to be (half-)closed*. Neither side closes the connection, so both programs must necessarily block on their respective read/receive, until something else disrupts the communication. Which basically means "unplugging the network cable", since TCP doesn't do any heartbeat by default or anything.

You need to understand two things about TCP. First, TCP is a stream-based protocol, not message-based. That means that if you want to send messages over TCP, you need to add your own framing - build your own messaging protocol on top of TCP's stream. You're assuming that the write on C# side will magically correspond to a read on the C++ side, but that simply isn't how TCP works.

Second, read/receive returns zero *only* when the stream is closed. This goes hand in hand with TCP being a stream-based protocol - it pretends there's an infinite amount of data to be read if you just waited for a bit for the buffer to be filled.

There's mainly two solutions to the problem. First is making sure you only read *one* message before continuing to the write. The easy way to do this is to just prefix the "message" you're sending with its length, so that the C++ side knows that when N bytes have been read, it has all the data it needs and can go  on. The second is to use asynchronous I/O to read *and* write at the same time. Have an outstanding read request at all times, and react to what you read, rather than trying to do a read-write-read sequential code.

If you only need a request-response patter, similar to HTTP, you could also just do a partial shutdown of the socket. You can use `TcpClient.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` to do this on the C# side. Both the applications will then be free to continue to process the response. Of course, when the response processing is done, you again want to shutdown, this time from the C++ side. The result is a closed connection on both sides, and a complete request-response cycle.